# searchkick suggestions not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, searchkick

So i have this in my view

```
<%= @events.try(:suggestions) %>
```

This inside my controller

```
@events = Newevent.search params[:search], suggest: true, partial: true, misspellings: {distance: 4}
```

and this inside my modal

```
  searchkick suggest: [:eventname]
```

Now when i try mistype something in. E.g. i have telephone in the eventname, and i type `tele` nothing shows expect this. `[]`

Any ideas?

Sam